# Parallel instantiation of methods in console application in C#

Tags: c#

I have declared my Enums like this: in reality there may be multiple enums for different countries.

for example:

```
public enum Country : long
{

    World = (long)1,
    India = (long)23424848,
    US = (long)23424977
}

public enum EgyptCities: long
{
    Cairo = (long)1521894,
    Alexandria = (long)1522006,
    Giza = (long)1521643
}
```

In my console application I want to loop through these enums which I have done.

```
 var country= Enum.GetValues(typeof(Country)).Cast<Country>();
 var egyptcity= Enum.GetValues(typeof(EgyptCities)).Cast<EgyptCities>();
```

For every enum there is an account associated which means for all countries an account is associated to run from which only functions can be invoked. for example in enum Country account1 only can run. for Cities enum account2 only can run and so on.

I want to run all accounts in parallel when I invoke this application.

```
account1
    (
     for all countries, do some operation
     )

account2

    ( for all egypt cities do an operation

    )

account3 
  (
     for all Indian cities do an operation.
   )
```

These are all independent operations.At the moment I am running all these operations one after another, but I want them to be parallel/asynchronous.

How well can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general answer is that there are *lots* of possible ways to execute code concurrently in your console application.

The most obvious would be to use `Task`. For example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task1 = Task.Run(() => ProcessAccount1()),
        task2 = Task.Run(() => ProcessAccount2()),
        task3 = Task.Run(() => ProcessAccount3());

    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);
}
```

…where each method `ProcessAccountX()` does something like:

```
void ProcessAccount1()
{
    var countries = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Country)).Cast<Country>();

    foreach (var country in countries)
    {
        // do some operation
    }
}
```